# Change strings based on a condition in a list using list comprehension

Tags: python, list-comprehension

Let's say I have a list like so:

```
a = ['abc1', '2def', 'g3h']
```

And I am trying to make it like this using list comprehension:

```
['abc', 'def', 'gh']
```

What I've tried:

```
[''.join([x for y in a for x in y if x.isalpha()])]
```

Which produces:

```
# ['abcdefgh']
```

Is there a neat way of achieving `['abc', 'def', 'gh']` using list comprehension?

Comment: `[re.sub('\d+', '', _) for _ in a]` and `import re`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `str.join` in a nested comprehension

**Ex:**

```
a = ['abc1', '2def', 'g3h']
print(["".join(j for j in i if j.isalpha()) for i in a])
# -> ['abc', 'def', 'gh']
```

Comment: Or use `not j.isdigit()` or `not j.isnumeric()` if the goal is just to exclude numeric characters, not keep solely alphabetic characters.

Comment: @ShadowRanger, do you think using `not isnumeric()` would be faster than `isalpha()`? Would this have something to do with the differences in items that need to be checked? I mean there are more letters than numbers.

Comment: @JonasPalačionis: I wouldn't worry about the speed here; do what's *correct* (do you *want* to blacklist numeric stuff? Whitelist alphabetic characters? If there is a whitespace character, do you keep it or not?). Odds are, you won't notice any difference in speed either way; interpreter overhead is likely to swamp the tiny differences. And fastest to the wrong answer is still wrong.

Answer (score 1):

If you can use regex, I would go for this:

```
import re
a = ['abc1', '2def', 'g3h']
[re.sub("\d+", "", x) for x in a]
```

Comment: Thanks for the regex approach!

Answer (score 0):

Use of map and filter

```
list(map(lambda x:"".join(filter(lambda y:y.isalpha(), x))  ,a))
```